# iOS AFNetworking Fail occurring

Tags: ios, objective-c, django, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

Error:
MultiValueDictKeyError at /login_or_signup Key 'name' not found in

Does not mention any line number or page, only mentions pages from Django set up files (not my code)

This block of iOS code fails

```
    //Now pass this to our login
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:BASE_URL];
    AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];
    NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            name, @"name",
                            email, @"email",
                            fbid, @"fbid",
                            nil];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"/login_or_signup/" parameters:params];
    NSLog(@"PARAMS %@", params);
    AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
//do something
}failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
        // your failure code here
        NSLog(@"FAILED %@", JSON);
    }]
```

Login or signup view code:

```
@csrf_exempt
def login_or_signup(request):

    user = False;
    username = False;
    email = "tmp@app.com"
    password = "tmppass"

    displayname = request.POST['name']
    fbid = request.POST['fbid']

    #Do we already have this user?

    if "email" in request.POST:
        email = request.POST['email']
        username = email
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(email=email)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            pass

    if fbid and not user:
        username = fbid
        try:
            user_profile = UserProfile.objects.get(fbid=fbid)
            user = user_profile.user
        except UserProfile.DoesNotExist:
            pass

    if not user:
        user = User.objects.create_user(fbid, email, password)

    #tastypie api_key
    api = ApiKey.objects.get(user=user)

    #Update user_profile:
    user_profile = user.get_profile()
    user_profile.username = displayname
    user_profile.fbid = fbid
    user_profile.save()

    dic = list()
    dic.append({
        'username':user_profile.username, 
        'user_profile_id':user_profile.id,
        'fbid':fbid,
        'api_username':user.username,
        'api_key':api.key
    })
    return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(dic, cls=DjangoJSONEncoder), mimetype='application/json')
```

Some handy iOS code

```
- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result {

    //Loading details about this FB user.  Send the details to Web App and create and/or login this user.

    NSLog(@"FACEBOOK RESULT %@ ", result);

    NSString * fbid = [result objectForKey:@"id"];
    NSString * email = [result objectForKey:@"email"];
    NSString * name = [result objectForKey:@"name"];

    [self loginOrSignup:name email:email fbid:fbid];
}
```

Also note that this NSLog up above does work, I can see the id, email, name, etc.

It is done sent to the loginorsignup iOS method which contacts the url via AFNetworking

Comment: Post the error message

Comment: Just the 500.html page is rendered

Comment: if you set `DEBUG` to `True` you should get a more informative error page

Comment: Thanks. MultiValueDictKeyError at /login_or_signup
Key 'name' not found in <QueryDict: {}>

Comment: Could you include the view code for your login_or_signup view?

Comment: Have now included the code

Comment: any ideas to what is happening??

Answer (score 0):

Try adding quotes to your includes:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',    
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),        
    url(r'^upload/', 'image.views.upload_file'),
    url(r'^login_or_signup', 'image.views.login_or_signup'),  
    url(r'^api/', include('v1_api.urls')) // mark the quotes
)
```

Also use quotes on the admin.site.urls if you don't have `from django.contrib import admin` in the top of your urls.py

Comment: The question has changed from a simple url fix - which was alright to start with to dealing with a multivaluedictkeyerror

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't reload the page to se the updates before i posted

Comment: That's fine :) any idea to what's wrong with the updated question

Comment: Can you post some more information from your 500 page? It's much easier when I can see the whole stacktrace. It gives you a clue about which line(s) are failing